# About twain component

Tags: delphi

How can I scan with twain without loading scanner manager? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have the same problem as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559659/delphitwain-how-to-show-form-setting/4567937

Comment: Which TWain component were you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ShowUI field of the TW_USERINTERFACE structure to FALSE.

Comment: More info can be found under the "Displaying the User Interface" section in the TWAIN specification (2.1)